# Toggle button visiblility with timer

Tags: android

I want use onTouch in android.
While ACTION_DOWN I want to make button flash in a pattern [ 3 seconds off 3 seconds on ]
I want to do this for 3 intervals of the pattern.
If either ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL is received before the 3 intervals are complete then cancel and leave button visible.
Otherwise call a function.

How would I accomplish this?

I have done similar using vibrator using a pattern.

```
long pattern[] = new long[] {0, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 2000};    
vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

Not all devices have vibrator so I wnt to flash button instead.
Any help would be much appreciated.

This code below works but is not very elegant. 
There must be a better way.

```
public class AndroidAnimButtonsActivity extends Activity 
{
CountDownTimer countDownTimerOn;
CountDownTimer countDownTimerOff;
CountDownTimer countDownTimerSOS;
ImageButton SOSButton;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    countDownTimerOn = new CountDownOn(100, 1000);
    countDownTimerOff = new CountDownOff(100, 1000);
    countDownTimerSOS = new CountDownSOS(3*1000, 1000);

    SOSButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sosbutton);

    SOSButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {

            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                SOSButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.panic2);
                countDownTimerOff.start();
                countDownTimerSOS.start();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                SOSButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.panic1);
                countDownTimerOn.cancel();
                countDownTimerOff.cancel();
                countDownTimerSOS.cancel();
                SOSButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL :
                SOSButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.panic1);
                countDownTimerOn.cancel();
                countDownTimerOff.cancel();
                countDownTimerSOS.cancel();
                SOSButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            }


            return false;
        }

    });

}

public class CountDownOn extends CountDownTimer
{

        public CountDownOn(long totalTime, long interval)
        {
            super(totalTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {

             SOSButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             countDownTimerOff.start();
         }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) 
       {

            long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;      
       }

    }
public class CountDownOff extends CountDownTimer
{

        public CountDownOff(long totalTime, long interval)
        {
            super(totalTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
         {
             SOSButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             countDownTimerOn.start();
         }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) 
       {

            long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;      
       }

    }
// CountDownTimer class
public class CountDownSOS extends CountDownTimer
{

        public CountDownSOS(long totalTime, long interval)
        {
            super(totalTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
         {

            SOSButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.panic2);
            SOSButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            countDownTimerOn.cancel();
            countDownTimerOff.cancel();

            sendMsg();
         }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) 
       {

            long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;      
       }

    }
public void sendMsg()
{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the actual code that you have attempted and we can try and help you fix it.

Comment: I updated above and added some code that does the job. It is not very elegant and there must be a better way.